# TCP connection reset by RST during connect()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

TCP connection reset by RST during `connect()`.

Many clients connect to the server and send data.
The client sends a [PSH,ACK] with data before sending the last ACK of the three-way handshake according to the packets that I captured with the tcpdump.

It leads to send rst by server-side. `NO_DELAY` option is used.
Judging from the data packet, except for the RST blocking packet, the data packet looks very normal.

At the beginning, I suspect that the firewall or hackers can obtain the source port through other means. RST attack is possible, but the customer said that there is no firewall and the This machine runs client and server programs.

In addition, this problem is difficult to reproduce, and it may take several weeks or longer. It occasionally receives such a packet and causes the connection to fail.

Connect code :

```c
do 
{
    r1 = connect(socketfd, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
} while (r1 < 0 && errno == EINTR);

if (setsockopt(socketfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
    &option_value, option_len) != 0) {}
```

Who knows what are the possible reasons? Please see the cap below:

Error packets:
[image: error packets]

Normal packates:
[image: normal packets]
Thank you.

Comment: You should consider the possibility that the reset is "forged" by a firewall or other security application that is unhappy with the connection.  Note that in the "error package" capture, the first reset is followed by an ack of the data sent with the PSH,ACK frame, and is further followed by a frame with a payload.  This is incompatible with the RST being sent by the local TCP stack if this is the actual order of packets being processed by the TCP stack. A TCP stack does not reset a connection and then continue to ackowledge and send data.

Comment: Also the ACK finishing the 3 way handshake is out of order with the PSH,ACK packet with the payload, which is an interesting edge case.  It is not clear to me how this could happen on the loopback on linux which does not have a layer 2; the packets get delivered directly to the tcp stack.  I know windows does have a layer 2 on the loopback but do not know if packets could arrive out of order.

Comment: We have confirmed that there is no firewall.
This place is really weird
TCP stack continue to ackowledge and send data after reset a connection. However, if the three-way handshake is not successful, will the psh packet cause the server to send rst?

Comment: As you said, there is no layer 2 on this machine, and the linux code implements loopback. But under normal circumstances, the psh package is always after ack.

Comment: So if you are using linux, I'm guessing this is a bug related to delivery of TCP packets over the loopback. Client sends SYN, server sends SYN,ACK.  Then client should ACK.  The ack should get delivered to a socket in the SYN queue.  Client app then sends some data.  A packet with PSH,ACK is sent to the server.  I'm guessing that some timing problem + some bug means that the PSH,ACK packet gets delivered first, and it can't find the socket, so the TCP stack sends a reset because there is no listening socket.  1/2

Comment: But then ACK gets delivered to the socket in the SYN queue and the socket moves to the accept queue and the server app accepts and sends some data.  Except the server has sent a RST to the client which closed the socket on the client side and the client TCP stack sends a RST.  If you don't need to use the loopback where the delivery of TCP packets follows a different code path, maybe this doesn't matter.  Seems unlikely to be a general problem (the ACK could be lost and the PSH,ACK could arrive first on a normal interface).  If you do need it on the loopback, try a differnet kernel version.2/2

Comment: What OS and version are on your client and server? Can your client connect to other servers?

Comment: "The client sends a [PSH,ACK] with data before sending the last ACK of the three-way handshake": no it doesn't. The ACK with the data is the ACK for the SYN/ACK. THere is nothing else for it to be for. The next ACK is for data from the server. Nothing is out of order here. Unclear whether there is any actual problem here to be solved.

Comment: @user207421Then what is the explanation for the RST?  And the fact that it continues to send data after sending the RST?

Comment: @user207421, The current problem is that in the process of many clients connecting to the server, only the client port 35046 receives the RST packet, it will abort the connection, but we have not found the reason why the RST packet is received here. Other clients can send and receive normally Data, because psh packets are after ack.

Comment: @JimD. Client and server carry out socket communication on this machine, the version is linux. Normal network packets enter the link layer from the ip layer, and then are sent to the network, and the packets sent to 127.0.0.1 are directly short-circuited at the IP layer, that is, the packets sent to the IP layer are directly received by the IP layer , No longer send down.

Comment: Is there a better way to track it? Originally, I wanted to add a bit of delay during the kernel connect to see if the psh packets will be advanced, which makes it easier to reproduce the problem, but checking the protocol stack code, the connect period seems to be serial.
Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just doing a `telnet` to the same server:port your client code is trying to reach?  That would at least help establish if it's a server issue vs a client code issue.  If the telnet fails, it's probably a server issue.  Otherwise, it's a client issue if telnet works.

Comment: @selbie, other client can work normal,It should explain that there is no problem with the server side.

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is, but strongly consider adding more retry logic if the `connect` call fails.  In our app, we do lots of exponential backoffs when we can't connect to the server (e.g. retry after 1 second, then 2 seconds, the 5 seconds... all the way up to five minutes).

Comment: @selbie, we also add some retry logic.The question now is not that the connect fails, but why the psh packet is sent before the third ack handshake.